# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at nextInt, next

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

This error has come up when I try to run this:

```
public class gift1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


        //declare and initialize scanner to read from gift1.in
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("gift1.in"));
        //declare and initialize PW to write result
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("gift1.out"));

        int np = scan.nextInt();
        List<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int o = 1; o<np; o++)
        {
            people.add(scan.next());
        }
        Map<String, Integer> monReceived = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(String person : people)
        {
            monReceived.put(person, 0);
        }
        Map<String, Integer> Initial = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i < np; i++)
        {
            String person = scan.next();
            int amount = scan.nextInt();
            int giveto = scan.nextInt();

            Initial.put(person, amount);

            int amountGift = 0;
            if(giveto > 0)
            {
                amountGift = (amount/giveto);
                monReceived.put(person, monReceived.get(person) + (amountGift%giveto));
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < giveto; j++)
            {
                String receivers = scan.next();
                monReceived.put(receivers, monReceived.get(receivers) + (amountGift - amountGift%giveto));

            }
        }
        for(String person : people)
        {
            out.println(person + " " + (monReceived.get(person) - Initial.get(person)));
        }
        out.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

do you know why this is? Do i need to add a try/catch? that is the only thought I have had. I have considered changing and using a BufferedReader but that reduces functionality that I need. What is the problem with my code? Thanks, Sam.

More details:

It says the errors are at:

```
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at gift1.main(gift1.java:24)
```

so I assume it is to do with the scanner but I can't see a problem hence I thought I should try try/catch but it hasn't worked as Ive done it.`

edit:the input data is shown below: the first line is an int so I don't understand the error.

```
   10 
    mitnik 
    Poulsen 
    Tanner 
    Stallman 
    Ritchie 
    Baran 
    Spafford 
    Farmer 
    Venema 
    Linus 
    mitnik 
    300 3 
    Poulsen 
    Tanner 
    Baran 
    Poulsen 
    1000 1 
    Tanner 
    Spafford 
    2000 9 
    mitnik 
    Poulsen 
    Tanner 
    Stallman 
    Ritchie 
    Baran 
    Farmer 
    Venema 
    Linus 
    Tanner
```

Comment: Just wild idea: maybe you are using `nextInt()` to read token which is not integer?

Comment: Are you sure? Consider changing `nextInt` which throws this exception (it should be in line `24` in `gift1.java` file) to `next` and print returned data.

Comment: Actually, that brings up a point. I thought you were talking about something different. It is an int at the top of input. Should I throw an exception? the error seems to be here.

Comment: I am new. How would I do that? It creates errors later.

Comment: I entered a breakpoint on line 25 and the error for line 24 no longer comes up. Obviously the new ones do but that isn't relevant currently.

Comment: I can't help you without knowing how your data you are trying to read look like (how are they formatted) and which line in your code is `24` (I assume you have some lines which handle importing classes like `HashMap`).

Comment: data is above. In the file it is all aligned perfectly. Line 24 is:

Comment: int np = scan.nextInt();

Comment: Strange, with data you posted I get this error for `int amount = scan.nextInt();`. `int np = scan.nextInt()` should work fine since first non-space data in your file is `10` which is integer. But problem sees to be related with fact that you are saying that you have 10 persons but your file have 11 of them (`mitnik` exists two times, at start and end of your list).

Comment: Initially, I only want it to take the first 10 people. Mitnik is actually then taken again with 'String person = scan.next();' which it is meant to. For a clearer explanation see here: http://cerberus.delos.com:790/usacoprob2?S=gift1&a=Ha7WbwFjJ5W

Comment: Could you take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23312033/1393766) and inform me if it solved your problem?

Comment: have you tried `int i = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading number of persons `10` but you are handling only `9` of them. Problem is your for loop. You are iterating from `1` till `9` (9 is last number `<10`).

You should start iterating from `0` so change

```
for(int o = 1; o<np; o++)
```

to

```
for(int o = 0; o<np; o++)
```

Otherwise you will be reading `9` persons so you will handle only

```
mitnik 
Poulsen 
Tanner 
Stallman 
Ritchie 
Baran 
Spafford 
Farmer
```

which will leave

```
Linus 
mitnik 
300 3 
Poulsen 
Tanner 
Baran 
Poulsen 
1000 1 
Tanner 
.
.
.
```

so in your next loop

```
String person = scan.next();
int amount = scan.nextInt();
int giveto = scan.nextInt();
```

`String person = scan.next();` will return `Linus`, but `int amount = scan.nextInt();` will try to parse `mitnik` which is not integer which will throw `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: I think that has fixed it. Doesn't seem to be working on USACO though. My code must be wrong. Ha. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it works on USACO website but not locally on eclipse. I am confused.

Comment: If both codes are same but you are getting different results then I suspect that you are handling different input. Double check if you are really using same code and if you didn't incorrectly edit `gift1.in` file.

Comment: ok, thanks.It was just a problem with the final calculations. :)